# Compare Arrays and Delete Arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, compare

I have below three sets ( arrays ) I need to perform an operation like this  `( (A-B)UC )` on. 
Can someone have the logic of this in Perl?
Here is my code I can able check for is B subset of A or not but I could not able to do "A-B":

```
my @array = (MAJOR,MINOR,MM,DD,YY);
my @exclude = (MM,MINOR,YY);
my @include = (LICENSE,VALID);
foreach (@exclude) {
if ( $_ ~~ @array ) {
print "\n $_ is defined in variables and it will be excluded \n";
@array = grep {!/\$_/} @array;
print "@array \n";
}
else {
print "\n $_ is not defined under variables please check the files \n";
exit 100;
}
}
foreach (@array){
print "$_ \n";
}
```

I suspect something is wrong in my logic with grep operation i.e. delete operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with the grep is that `$_` in the outer loop is redefined inside the grep block to each element of `@array`. You need to have different names. Also, your regex was lacking anchors; however, instead of a regex, just use string inequality. Try this:

```
my @array = qw(MAJOR MINOR MM DD YY);
my @exclude = qw(MM MINOR YY);
my @include = qw(LICENSE VALID);
foreach my $e (@exclude) {
  if ( $e ~~ @array ) {
    print "\n $e is defined in variables and it will be excluded \n";
    @array = grep {$e ne $_} @array;
    print "@array \n";
  } else {
    print "\n $e is not defined under variables please check the files \n";
    exit 100;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use strict and warnings to alert you to many pitfalls in perl.

A hash is the most natural way to represent a set in perl.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @array = ('MAJOR','MINOR','MM','DD','YY');
my @exclude = ('MM','MINOR','YY');
my @include = ('LICENSE','VALID');

my %set;
# add @array to set
@set{@array} = ();
# remove @exclude
delete @set{@exclude};
# add @include
@set{@include} = ();
# array of elements resulting
my @result = sort keys %set;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `set` to do those kind of operations. I used a non-standard module `Set::Scalar` to help me with it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Set::Scalar;

my @array = qw(MAJOR MINOR MM DD YY);
my @exclude = qw(MM MINOR YY);
my @include = qw(LICENSE VALID);

my $array_set = Set::Scalar->new(@array);
my $exclude_set = Set::Scalar->new(@exclude);
my $include_set = Set::Scalar->new(@include);

my $result = $array_set->difference($exclude_set)->union($include_set);

use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper @$result;
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl
```

That yields:

```
$VAR1 = 'VALID';
$VAR2 = 'MAJOR';
$VAR3 = 'DD';
$VAR4 = 'LICENSE';
```

Comment: it is usable , is there any way to compare two arrays using Scalar operations.